# IMPUTE2 missing filter option

Tags: impute2

I went through the manuals and can't find the meaning of the below flag:

```
-filt_rules_l 'filter==0'
```

Here is the link to manual for this flag: [filt_rules_l](https://mathgen.stats.ox.ac.uk/impute/filtering_options.html)

Can anyone explain?

IMPUTE version:

```
impute_v2.3.1_x86_64_dynamic
```

---

**Edit:** The full IMPUTE2 code is irrelevant, I am **not** using the command to impute, I received an imputed data and the script used to impute. This one flag was a mystery to me. I will update the post with impute software version when I find out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never used this program, but reading the manual in the link it has to mean the following.

The manual says:

> Writing `-filt_rules_l 'eur.maf<0.05'` on the command line would tell the program to remove any variants with `eur.maf` values less than 0.05 from the reference panel.

So, `-filt_rules_l 'filter==0'` would mean that the program removes any variants with `filter` values of 0 from the reference panel. In the legend file there should be a column named `filter`, which are filtered out when the value is 0.

Here is the example legend file, in your case there must be a custom additional column named *"filter"*:

```
$ head ALL_1000G_phase1integrated_v3_chr1_impute.legend

id position a0 a1 afr.aaf amr.aaf asn.aaf eur.aaf afr.maf amr.maf asn.maf eur.maf
rs58108140 10583 G A 0.0407 0.1713 0.1311 0.2071 0.0407 0.1713 0.1311 0.2071
rs189107123 10611 C G 0.0142 0.0276 0.0140 0.0211 0.0142 0.0276 0.0140 0.0211
```

Comment: Thank you, are you suggesting that reference panel has column named "filter"? I will have to check. But I think "eur.maf" column is calculated on the fly from the reference file, need to check.

Comment: If you want to use your command it should. If not it won't work, and you need to find the column on which you want to filter.

Comment: Yes, sorry I have missed the `_l` bit, meaning this filter works from legend file, which in my case apparently had a modified version of Phase3 legend file with extra `"filter"` column. All makes sense now. Thank you.